# Creating a picture frame with arduino and bluetooth module HC-05

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am planning to make a arduino picture frame which gets data from an android phone through bluetooth module HC-05.Most of the example in the internet gives information about serial communication over the bluetooth module. Is it possible to send an image file over HC-05 to arduino?

Please help me out on this!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Of course... An image is just a bunch of bytes, so you will be able to transfer it.

Ok, you will have a lot of troubles on the arduino side because of the low memory on the device, but.. Yes, you can.

The best way is to load the image in the application, then send it pixel-by-pixel on the serial interface and, on the arduino side, pass it directly to the screen. This will avoid keeping it in memory...

Otherwise you will have to add external memory, better if with a fast interface.

And of course it will be slow (you won't be able to see an animation.. arduino is really slow) but... I think it can work.

Comment: Just as a reference, if you have a 640x480 image, 256 colors (so 8bit/pixel) it's 307200 bytes. With a 2 bit/byte overhead (start and stop bits) it's a total of 3072000 bits. At 115200 bit/s (a fast UART communication) it's 26 seconds. If both devices support 1Mbit UART (the fastest "standard" uart I know) it's still 3 seconds. As you can see, UART is kind of slow...